Unable to pass command-line options to systemx from IPC::System::Simple
I'm struggling to pass command-line options to a systemx command from Perl's IPC::System::Simple module. Please find my minimal example below:
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use v5.40;
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings;
use IPC::System::Simple qw(systemx);

# set executable name
my $exe = 'hostname';

# set GNU time command
my $time = "/opt/local/bin/gtime";

# set log file name
my $ofile = $exe . '.log';

# set GNU time command options
my $opt = ' -a -f %e\t%U\t%S\t%P\t%M\t%c\t%w\t%F\t%R -o ' . $ofile;

systemx($time, $opt, $exe);

When I call systemx without options to gtime, it works well:
# systemx($time, $exe);

lobachevsky
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.01elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1152maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (1major+189minor)pagefaults 0swaps

When I call systemx with options to gtime, my script fails:
# systemx($time, $opt, $exe);

gtime: cannot run  -a -f %e\t%U\t%S\t%P\t%M\t%c\t%w\t%F\t%R -o hostname.log: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 50%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1040maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+83minor)pagefaults 0swaps
"/opt/local/bin/gtime" unexpectedly returned exit value 127 at ./profiler_mini.pl line 21.

I must be missing something obvious here.

You have multiple errors here:

If you want to use escape sequences like \t you have to use double quotes around the string constant, like in "token\ttoken".
Why do you put a space at the beginning of the string constant that you assign to $opt?
The usage for systemx (and system) is $executable, @args. The first element of @args in your case is the string ' -a -f YOUR_FORMAT hostname.log'. Because it does not start with a hyphen (-), the command gtime interprets it as the executable name and that executable does not exist.
The command time/gtime expects another command to run as a mandatory argument. I assume that you want to run the command hostname but you do not specify it.

This will work:
systemx $time, '-a', '-f', "%e\t%U\t%S\t%P\t%M\t%c\t%w\t%F\t%R", '-o', 'hostname.log', 'hostname'

You probably would have been able to understand the problem yourself by adding some debugging output:
print "time: '$time'\n";
print "opt: '$opt'\n";
print "exe": '$exe'\n";

Do not forget the single quotation marks ' or some other delimiters.  Extra whitespace or empty variable values are a common source of bugs.

To summarise, each command-line option should be a separate element of the @args array. Thank you!

That is at least a reasonably safe approach. Try perldoc -f system for more details.

@mabalenk, Re "each command-line option", Note quite. Each argument to the program should be a separate argument to systemx. So -f and %e... needs to be passed as separate arguments even though it's one option, and hostname.log isn't an option at all. /// The whole point of systemx is that it never uses a shell, so you can't pass a shell command (or a part of one).
